# How do I efficiently select specific line numbers from a list of records?

Tags: text-processing, sed, filter

I want to take a list of numbers representing *line numbers* of a source file I want to filter and filter those lines from the source file. How I can build a unix pipeline to extract these lines from the source file?

The pipeline might look like:

```
cat sourcefile.tsv | some-filter linenumbers.txt  > extractedrecords.tsv
```

I can't think of a combination of unix tools to do this off the top of my head. The fallback is to write a bash script that does `sed -n [number]p sourcefile.tsv` for every number in linenumbers.txt.

If my fallback plan is reasonably efficient compared to alternatives, please let me know that too.

Comment: `sed -nf - sourcefile.tsv <linenumbers.txt >extractrecords.csv` - but *linenumbers* would need to look like `[num]p` for each line... If it doesn't already then `sed 's/[^0-9]//g;s/[0-9]\{1,\}/&p/' <linenumbers.txt | sed -nf - sourcefile.tsv > extractedrecords.tsv`

Comment: What is the format of `linenumbers.txt`?

Comment: That is called the "useless use of cat": `some-filter linenumbers.txt <sourcefile.tsv >extractedrecords.tsv`

Comment: @jasonwryan just a list of plain numbers, one per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `linenumbers.txt` has one number per line

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0]; next};FNR in a' linenumbers.txt sourcefile.csv > extractedrecords.tsv
```

Might do the job.

Or, with `bash`

```
join  -t':' -o2.1,2.2  <(sort linenumbers.txt) <(awk '{print NR":"$0}' \
sourcefile.csv | sort -k1,1 -t':')  | sort -k1,1n -t':' | cut -f2- -d':'
```

All the extra jumping through hoops is needed because `join` does not support numerically sorted input files

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with sed: all you need to do is to transform your list of line numbers to be followed by a `p` and a newline, and use that as a sed script. For example, if you have a space-separated list:

```
lines="2 3 5 7 11 13"
<sourcefile.tsv sed -n "$(echo "$lines" | sed 's/$/p/; s/ /p\n/')"  >extractedrecords.tsv
```

Awk is another possibility.

```
lines="2 3 5 7 11 13"
export lines
<sourcefile.tsv awk '" "ENVIRON["lines"]" " ~ " "NR" "' >extractedrecords.tsv
```